# Synaptics touchpad stops working after hibernating a Dell XPS 16

Tags: drivers, hibernate, touchpad

I am currently experimenting with using Ubuntu as a my main OS instead of Windows 7. So far, pretty much everything is working fine, except for an issue that I am having with my touchpad.

I have a Dell XPS 16 (1640) with a Synaptics touchpad. It works out of the box, but it seems that it stops working after returning from hibernation mode.

This problem has also been addressed in an earlier bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/317270 but judging from this bug report, it should be fixed by now.

I am running the 2.6.35-23-generic-pae kernel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may be hit by this bug instead:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/715267

A workaround is suggested, to restore touchpad functionality reload the psmouse module, in a terminal do:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

If this solves the problem then this is likely the bug affecting you. Note that a fix is in recent kernels, so upgrading to either Ubuntu 11.10 (with kernel 3.0.0-16) or 12.04 should solve the issue.